# Загрузка JSON файла в multipart/form-data (Java)

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, postman

Я сделал **POST** запрос с помощью **Postman**, но не знаю как сделать точно также на **Java**:

Тут происходит авторизация *(SECRET_KEY : 12345)*:
[image: Тут происходит авторизация (SECRET_KEY : 12345)]

---

Это **POST** запрос:
[image: POST запрос]

---

Запрос должен происходить на **Android** устройстве, файл называется *images.json*

Я находил подобные вопросы на английском **Stack Overflow**, но в них был нерабочий *legacy* код, в частности устаревшие классы, которые не работают в новых версиях.

Также искал разные библиотеки, нашел 2 это **Retrofit** (Нет документации) и **HttpClient** (Как раз в нем много устаревших классов,которые не работают в новых версиях), возможно есть другие.

---

*Как сделать такой POST-запрос? Буду благодарен за любой ресурс, совет, помощь и т.д. Если есть какие вопросы, которые помогут в решении вопроса задавайте.*